# How to add to an already existing variable in python?

Tags: python

I know this is a very simple question, but I couldn't find it. Basically what I'm trying to is have `a=2`, `b=3`, and I need `a+b=b` so when I add `a` and `b` what it equals needs to be `b`.

Comment: `b = a + b` is what you're looking for, or `b += a`

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
b = a + b
# make b equal to a + b
```

Or

```
b += a
# increase the value of b by a
```

Answer (score 2):

declare variables

```
a = 2
b = 3
```

operates

```
b = a+b
```

Comment: You can even recommend the usual `b += a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the += shorthand for summation on variable.

For instance, in order to add in the value of `a` in the `b` variable, and retaining the last value of `b`:

```
b += a
```

This is the same thing as saying: `b = a + b`. Both works fine. Choose as you feel is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example:

First, initialize your variables:

```
a = 2
b = 3
print a, b
```

Output: 2 3

You can add a to b, this way:

```
b += a
print b
```

Output: 5

You can also add to the actual value of b 10

```
b = 10+b
print b
```

Output: 15

Comment: Side note: I encourage you to read and follow PEP 8: it contains Python style recommendations that are widely followed. This will make your code more legible (I fixed the style in your answer so that it follows the common convention).